# Is there a console GUI widget for Java? Eclipse Console view is an option?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'd like to create a console-based UI. Do you know about any Java console widget? I mean, is there some project that have built something like a "JConsole"? Swing or SWT, anything is ok.

Is it possible to use Eclipse Console View alone in an application? It it a widget itself?

Comment: What user interaction will you have in that console window? The Eclipse Console view is a UI Window too. Perhaps you just need a simple widget where you can append text?

Comment: Besides appending text output, the point of a console is getting input from the user's keyboard. A JTextArea would do if the point was simply appending text. But, besides appending, it should be possible to read from this window too. Maybe having it to feed an InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this project](http://code.google.com/p/gritty). That's what I was talking about. I think I'll can reuse its components.